# Download all images from Google Image Search URL using C#

Tags: c#, image, download, google-image-search

I am looking to write/find C# code that downloads all the images found at a 'Google Image Search' URL. The images would be saved to a folder on my computer.

I've researched online this functionality and haven't found anything yet. Any suggestions on how to do this or where to begin?

The following is a 'Google Image Search' URL I'll be using: http://images.google.com/images?q=srk&start=0&ndsp=20

Comment: The ones which I looked all are 2 years before and few API's are deprecated ... Thought this would be help me

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **PHP** approach

`$text = file_get_contents('http://images.google.com/images?q=srk&start=0&ndsp=20');
$dcmnt = new DOMDocument(); 
$dcmnt->loadHTML( $text );
foreach($dcmnt->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node){`

you can add any html tag where the `'a'` is and manipulate the page source .
use `file_get_contents()` to download the image files.